# upgrading to MySQL 5.7 from 5.6

Tags: windows-7, mysql, mysql5

I downloaded MySQL Installer 5.7.10, thinking it'd update the version of MySQL I have from 5.6.27 to 5.7.10 and...  it doesn't seem to be able to.

I could manually backup my databases, uninstall 5.6.27, install 5.7.10 and then restore the databases, but that seems like a lot of work when it seems like the installer ought to be able to do that.

Is there a better way than what I've just described to perform the update?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be able to" What exactly happens when you try?

Comment: I don't know how to try. The option to select 5.7.* is unavailable. At least in the screens I was looking at. I used the installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ . I ran it and in the "Select Products To Upgrade" screen there isn't a way to change the version you're upgrading to. It just does the latest 5.6.*. Asking me to try when, near as I can tell, it's not possible to try, is like asking me to try to run on a treadmill on the International Space Station (ie. since I'm not on it and it's doubtful I ever will be it's hard to even try)