# How to upgrade mysql server in windows?

Tags: windows, mysql, mysql5

I am attempting to upgrade MySql server from version 5.6 to 5.7. After installing MySql server 5.6, I proceed to upgrade it by launching the installation wizard through .msi file of MySql5.7. It detects the existing server(5.6) on the system and gives me options to upgrade it but when I click that it look for upgrades through product catalog update. 
There is an option to install MySQL 5.7 server but it creates a separate instance, service and directory. I want the existing server to be upgraded, Is there any way to do that through this wizard?

[When I try to upgrade 5.6 to 5.7 I get this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqQPe.png)
Is there any way by which we can upgrade by not referring to product catalog update?

Why is it looking for upgrade online when the msi for 5.7 is already present in the "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache" folder?
 [Here is a screen shot of the product cache folder, it already has msi for 5.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiZmc.png)

It is noteworthy, that no such thing happens when I upgrade from 5.6.31 to 5.6.35. The upgrade is seamless and does not require any internet connection, why it happens differently when I try to upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7?

following is the link to a similar question - 
[upgrading to MySQL 5.7 from 5.6](https://superuser.com/questions/1019562/upgrading-to-mysql-5-7-from-5-6)

Comment: Check this official pages [1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html). [2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html).

Comment: Hi @vembutech, thanks. I tried to upgrade 5.6 using the method specified, for me it is point no. - "6. using MySQL Installer" in the [first link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html).On opening 5.7's msi and Pressing the upgrade button for MySql5.6 server gives me a message that - "none of the products have upgrades available". Although, there is an option to update catalog, but it attempts to connect to the internet. Instead, I want to use the msi for 5.7 that is present  in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache" folder, can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the MSI based installer will let you upgrade the minor versions but not the major. So you can update 5.5.xx to a newer 5.5.xx but not to 5.7. It seems to want to create multiple installs with a new install for each major version, so a 5.5 install alongside a 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

It can't upgrade the server probably because something is incompatible, or the upgrader can't check for updates from server because firewall/ip blocking.

My advice, is to dump all databases in your MySQL server, uninstall MySQL 5.6 and perform a clean install of 5.7. Then, restore all dumps. However, if you have no great need to do an upgrade, you can also avoid to do it.

Comment: Hi, actually I intended to upgrade MySql5.6 through a power shell script. Therefore I was interested in knowing how could I do an "in-place upgrade" . I have the msi for 5.7, I want to upgrade existing 5.6 MySQL server to 5.7, how can I do that without having to uninstall previous version, is there any provision for that?